# Algorithm to find a path that visits every vertex in a directed graph AT LEAST once

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-graph, strongly-connected-graph

I have an SCC of a directed graph. I want to find a path that visits every vertex in this SCC at least once, starting from a vertex s. I know this may be an NP problem. Regardless, how do I solve this?

Comment: A Hamiltonian path (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) visits each vertex *exactly* once, and determining if one exists is NPC. However, visiting *at least* once seems easier - except that it might not be a path any longer...

Comment: If you need _any_ path (not necessary simple), then you may find _some_ path from 1 to 2, then _some_ path from 2 to 3, so on (1, 2, 3, ... are the numbers of vertices in your SCC). And if you need the simple path then @gilleain correctly noticed that this is an NP-complete Hamiltonian path problem.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Thanks! I needed some path(walk) ; not a simple path. This helped.

Comment: @AmiteshSrivastava Great! I added my comment as an answer so you could formally accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need any path (not necessary simple), then you may find some path from 1 to 2, then some path from 2 to 3, so on (1, 2, 3, ... are the numbers of vertices in your SCC). And if you need the simple path then *gilleain* correctly noticed in comments that this is an NP-complete Hamiltonian path problem.